Issue while upgrading to Service Principle from Service Accounts
We are upgrading our Azure Runbook from using service account to service principle(Azure AD authentication using Certificate).
This runbook perform provisioning and apply custom template to SharePoint site. Site Provisioning worked fine with it. but while applying template using Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate it is throwing below error. We can't use Pnp.Powershell as many other scripts are using that
{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}
What permission is azure app is missing. Currently below permission is given through azure app
Permission on Azure APP
I have tried to find out documentation on Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate but seems documentation is removed now by PnP
